# Java: How would I draw a line at an angle other than 45 degrees or zero degrees etc.?

Tags: java, math, line, angle, radians

I've been researching fractals and decided to give it a try, but immediately ran into a much simpler issue. I can't draw a line at any angle other than 0, 45, 90, ... etc.

The problem:
My angle is an integer, and I'm using Math.toRadians(angle) to calculate the angle itself as its drawn. When I draw the line, I have to cast (int) to the double produced from Math.toRadians(), which causes me to lose the angle itself and I believe is what prevents the line from being drawn.

The code I'm using: `

```
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    int angle = 90; 

    int startX = getWidth()/2;
    int startY = getHeight()/2;
    int length = 100;

    int endX = startX + (int)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * length;
    int endY = startY + (int)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * length;

    g2d.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY);
```

`

Solution:

```
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    int angle = 91; 

    int startX = getWidth()/2;
    int startY = getHeight()/2;
    int length = 100;



    int endX = startX + (int)(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * length);
    int endY = startY + (int)(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * length);

    g2d.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY);
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: You should cast to `int` *after* multiplying by `length`.

Comment: ^--- `(int)(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * length)`

Comment: sine and cosine are real numbers, quotients in the range [-1,1] defining an angle. Retain their precision in any computation until the last moment if you need to cast to integer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was stumped by something so dumb haha.

Comment: @A.Ferguson Don't add a solution to your question. That's what answers are for.

Comment: @laune Actually, I find casting these values (trimming off the floating point) gives slightly more accurate values IMHO, but I'd be using `Line2D`, but that's me ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are a victim of operator precedency. You need

```
int endX = startX + (int) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * length);
int endY = startY + (int) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * length);
```

Answer (score 1):

For best precision, use Math.round():

```
int endX = startX + (int)Math.round(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * length);
int endY = startY + (int)Math.round(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * length);
```

You may not notice any difference in your drawing on screen, but lost precision can add up to visible glitches.

Comment: For better precision use 2D Graphics and the Shapes API which supports double ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Does the pixel (x,y) represent a rectangle ([x,x+1],[y,y+1]) or ([x-0.5,x+0.5],[y-0.5,y+0.5])? Should a programmer worry about that? E.g., watch out for different interpretations of fractional values against the integer pixel grid? I've never come across a discussion of this (but didn't try to find one).

Comment: It's all about context, depending on how it's configured, the Graphics API could use anti-analising to render the fractional elements